# Get the optional value from model's property

Tags: ios, swift

In my code:

```
let userStatic:UserStaticSwift = UserStaticSwift.sharedInstance() // UserStaticSwift save the info

if userStatic.nor_businessName != "" {
     
    self.nor_name.text = userStatic.nor_businessName
    self.nor_vauth.isHidden = false
}else {
    self.nor_name.text = "un bind terant"
    self.nor_vauth.isHidden = true
}
```

The result is a unexpected:

`self.nor_name.text` will be set: `"Optional(the real value)"`, but I want be set `"the real value"`.

But the `userStatic`'s property is a `optional`, I just want the value `the real value`, not the below:

```
(lldb) po userStatic.nor_businessName
"Optional(the real value)"
```

How can I take out the value, not the `Optional(value)` ?

---

**EDIT -3**

Additional Information to show more:

In the `@objc class UserStaticSwift:NSObject, NSCoding`:

```
self.nor_status = UtilSwift.getIntFromAny(dic["status"] as Any)
self.nor_phone = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["phone"])
self.nor_name = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["name"])
self.nor_definition = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["definition"])
self.nor_log = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["logo"])
self.nor_businessName = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["businessName"]) //  attention, is there if I use the `dic["businessName"] as Any`, then will get the Optional value, so I pass the `dic["businessName"]`
```

In the `UtilSwift`:

```
class func getStrFromAny(_ any:Any?) -> String {
    
    if let nonNil = any, !(nonNil is NSNull) {
        
        return String(describing: nonNil)
    }
    return ""
}
```

---

Comment: self.nor_name.text = "\(userStatic.nor_businessName)" now test in application

Comment: try using  guard let let name = businessName else { return } ?

Comment: @aircraft when you insert data of `nor_businessName` in to model, make sure its not an optional string

Comment: @EI Captain Great answer, I am thinking about the issue maybe there, but if have done this how to resolve it?

Comment: you can't as its already store as a string and `nor_businessName` at this point takes whole `Optional(value)` as a String and in model I think you make `nor_businessName` an empty string .. so its not nil at any cost I think

Comment: @aircraft not an issue this side... your model has a non optional string means non empty string .. .so better to check condition when you insert the string into model

Comment: can you check the data Type of `nor_businessName`? is it String kind?

Comment: @Piyush Rathi It has written in my post: `(lldb) po userStatic.nor_businessName
"Optional(the real value)"`

Comment: Where (or how) do you set the `nor_businessName`? My guess is that you use string interpolation like this `nor_businessName = "\(someOptionalString)"` where `someOptionalString` is a not-unwrapped optional String.

Comment: @HAS I set `nor_businessName ` when model is initial, and in there it be set to ` Opitional`, so I can change the type when initial the model, but I don't know if it can be change the opitional type after the `nor_businessName ` been setted.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show the code of `UserStaticSwift`?

Comment: @HAS See my `EDIT-3`, if when I initial the `UserStaticSwift`, I if set the `
self.nor_businessName = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["businessName"] as Any)`, this will make `self.nor_bussinessName` to be `Opitional`, and If I set `self.nor_businessName = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["businessName"] )`, This the issue will not appear,  I know the issue source, I can solve it in the `UserStaticSwift` initial method, but can I resolve it after the `self.nor_businessName = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["businessName"]  as Any)`? That is the `self.nor_businessName` is `Opitional` now.

Comment: Okay, hopefully last one: can you show the `getStrFromAny` function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129861/discussion-between-aircraft-and-has).

Comment: @HAS In my `edit-3`, check it.

Comment: Ah sorry! :/ and there's your problem! :) `String(describing:)` uses the description of the runtime type. I don't know why but the type of `nonNil` still seems to be an optional. Since you're then passing an optional string the description is "Optional(YOURSTRING)". Thats the only explanation I am think of. Can you replace it with `if let nonNilString = any as? String, !(any is NSNull) { return nonNilString }`

Comment: @HAS I know the issue here, as you say I can avoid that, and because it is initial the `UserStaticSwift ` , my question is if the `UserStaticSwift `'s `nor_businessName ` has been set to `Opitional`, when use the `nor_businessName`, how can we solve that ? or is no way to do that ?

Comment: No, this variable was never optional. What *is* optional is the return value of your dictionary subscript. TBH I still don't understand your question :( As you said you know how to solve the issue (so that "Optional(the real value)" becomes "the real value"). What else is there to explain? :)

Answer (score 0):

try this(adding ! at optional element):

```
po userStatic.nor_businessName!
```

**UPDATE:**

If above not worked for you, then you should try this:

```
guard let value = userStatic.nor_businessName  else {
print("fails");
return;
}

self.nor_name.text = value;
```

Comment: I have tested before ask question, system suggest me to delete the `!`.

Comment: See Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
if let value = userStatic.nor_businessName as? String{
self.nor_name.text = value
}
```

and make sure your value in userStatic.nor_businessName is not with optional text.

Answer (score 0):

it's like @mehul wrote.
the `!` at the end of a variable "unwraps" the content

it seems that your var is not really a optional... it looks more like that the this "optional"-thing is added as `String`. 
You should look at the declaration of `userStatic.nor_businessName`.

Comment: I have tried using `!` before asking question, see my `EDIT - 1`